# Ein Mishpat Ner Mitswa and Massoret HaShass

Tags: talmud-bavli, commentaries, maseches-kesubos

In today's daf [ketubot 6a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=6&format=pdf) can you please translate for me the Ein Mishpat Ner Mitswa and Massoret HaShass parts. I do not know how to read them with all these abreviations ... It could really help.

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=9 -- they have a good reference of Hebrew abbreviations/acronyms.

Answer (score 2):

The Ein Mishpat Ner Mitswa lists the places that these subjects are mentioned in the Halachic works. Each paragraph has a number (counting from the beginning of the chapter), and one or more letters indicating where on the page it's referring to.

> **21** א Tur and Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim, chapter 320, section 18.
>
> **22** א ב Maimonides, chapter 5 of the Laws of Prohibited Relations, law 18, 19. Semag, negative commandments, 111. (Tur and Shulchan Aruch, Even Ha'ezer, chapter 63, section 1; Tur and Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah, chapter 193, section 1.)

The Massoret HaShass includes notes of two kinds: other places in the Talmud where concepts are mentioned, and variants in the text. Each note has a letter indicating where on the page it's referring to.

> א) Other versions do not include this word.
>
> ב) [Shabbos 111a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=111&format=pdf), [Bechoros 25a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=32&daf=25&format=pdf), [see there].
>
> ג) [Shabbos 75a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=75&format=pdf), [103a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=75&format=pdf), [111b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=111b&format=pdf), [117a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=117&format=pdf), [120b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=120b&format=pdf), 133a, 143a, Bechorot 25a, Sukkah 33b, [Beitzah 36a].
>
> ד) Niddah 11b, 64b.
>
> ה) [Entry סבר.] (The related Tosafot quotes the Aruch; this note gives the precise location.)
>
> ו) ["Even though an activity which isn't needed for itself is forbidden according to Rabbi Shimon; where it doesn't benefit him at all, it's more permissible." This is the version in the responsum of the Re'em, section 94.]
>
> ז) Rashal has the text ומיהו (*however*).
>
> ח) [See Tosafot on Shabbat 41b, entitled מיחם (*hot water container*).]
>
> ט) This piece belongs on the other side of this page.

Comment: +1 But how did you decide on translating 'nicha leih' as needed?

Comment: @user6591 Good point; corrected.

Comment: Thanks. For the Ein Mishpat part. What are in hebrew the word after Maimonide and the two words after Smag?

Comment: Note that most editions don't have _m'sores hashas_ numbered.

Comment: @far22 פ"ה, which stands for 'פרק ה ([chapter 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=27&perek=5&halocha=18)). After Smag is לאוין קיא, which means [the negative-commandments part, section 111](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20520&pgnum=142).

Comment: I understand what means 111 but what does the first word mean?

Comment: The Smag is split into two main parts: one dealing with positive commandments (e.g. wear _tefillin_); one with negative commandments (e.g. don't live with a _niddah_)