# Ein Mishpat in opposite direction

Tags: talmud-gemara, rambam, mishna, shulchan-aruch, tur

The Ein Mishpat commentary notes where the topic in Mishna or Gemara is referenced in the Rambam or Tur/Shulchan Aruch (other relevant question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53622/ein-mishpat-ner-mitswa-and-massoret-hashass)).

Is there a work that reverses the order with the same information - e.g. listing the Rambam in order and which mishnayos and gemaros are referenced?

Alternatively, has anyone complied the Ein Mishpat topics in a spreadsheet, where you could easily sort by one column or the other?

Comment: The Be’er Hagolah on Shulchan Aruch lists the Gemara source for each Halacha

Comment: @Chatzkel I wonder how often it differs from Ein Mishpat

Answer (score 3):

There are many works that give the sources for Rambam. The first and most similar to Ein Mishpat is Migdal Oz. That just gives you the chapter. Others are Maggid Mishneh and Kessef Mishnah, but they are more in depth, and explain beyond just sources. The Frankel edition of Rambam has additional sources listed on the side.

For Shulchan Aruch, there is Be'er Hagolah. The Shulchan Aruch incorporates much post-Talmudic scholarship, which he also references. His descendant the Vilna Gaon added more sources in his commentary to Shulchan Aruch.

In addition, Sefaria.org lets you click on any gemara, Rambam, or Shulchan Aruch quotation and it will link to the other places it is quoted or discussed.